# How to call a function without blocking the execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been working on a small PoC where I am trying to do a I/O Bound application to execute functions without being blocked. Currently I have created something like this:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

found_products = []

site_catalog = [
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sneakers",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/T-shirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sweatshirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Shirts"
]


def threading_feeds():
    # Create own thread for each URL as we want to run concurrent
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(monitor_feed, site_catalog)


def monitor_feed(link: str) -> None:
    old_payload = product_data(...)

    while True:
        new_payload = product_data(...)

        if old_payload != new_payload:
            for links in new_payload:
                if links not in found_products:
                    logger.info(f'Detected new link -> {found_link} | From -> {link}')
                    # Execute filtering function without blocking, how?
                    filtering(link=found_link)

        else:
            logger.info("Nothing new")
            time.sleep(60)
            continue


def filtering(found_link):
    # More code will be added in the future to handle logical code parts
    ...
    # Test
    time.sleep(60)
```

**Problem:** Currently the issue is that whenever we enter the row `filtering(link=found_link)` there will be a call to `filtering(...)` which sleeps for 60 seconds (This is only a mock data, in the future I will have a logical code part instead), what it does then is that the monitor_feed stops the execution and waits until the `filtering()` is finished.

**My Question:** I wonder how can I be able to execute the `filtering(...)` and still continue to loop through the monitor_feed without being blocked when we call `filtering(...)`?

Comment: Remove the `time.sleep()` call from `filtering()` and in `monitor_feed` outdent the `time.sleep()` call, and remove the `continue` so the sleep is executed regardless of the `if` result.

Comment: @barny Well the idea in the future is to have more code inside filtering which will do some logical stuff. I used a `time.sleep` as example as we do not want to be blocked when we call the `filtering()` or am I missing something here?

Comment: Please explain this in your question as this is not obvious/explained at all.

Comment: @barny I have explained it at the very bottom :) You might have missed it? or do you mean that it is still not explained well?

Comment: The paragraph above says blocking execution is the correct behaviour.

Comment: @barny Correct, the code is supposed to do that but then I asked in my question if I can execute the `filtering(...)` without being blocked as well. Do you want me to rephrase it?

Comment: you will have to run it in separated thread.

Comment: @furas How would I be able to do that? :o

Comment: funny is you ask how to use `thread` but you use `threads` in `ThreadPoolExecutor` :) You have standard module [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) and you can start thread with `threading.Thread(target=filtering, args=(found_link,))`

Comment: @furas I thought it was not possible to use a nested threading, basically a thread inside a thread if that make sense? :P Thought that is a big no thing to do. But do I need to kill the threading.Thread then once its done?

Comment: I don't tested nested threads but they should work. You don't have to kill it - but you may assing to variable (`t = ...`) and later use `t.join()` to wait for its end. (I forgot you have to use `t.start()` to start thread). If you don't want to run nested thread then you may try to run some thread at start - and this thread may run loop with `Queue` to get data `found_link`, run `filtering` and wait for next `found_link` . You could even try to use another `ThreadPoolExecutor` for this - with submit() instead of map() - this way it should better use threads.

Comment: Or maybe it would work even with current `ThreadPoolExecutor` ?

Comment: @furas With current ThreadPoolExecutor it does not seem to work as it blocks if I reach the `filtering(...)` unless I add another `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:` inside the `monitor_feed()` but I dont think that is correct? Or what do you think?

Comment: you should try `executor.submit(filtering, found_link)` instead of `filtering(...)`

Comment: @furas Do you mean to do that without adding another `with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:` inside monitor_feed()?

Comment: @furas Do you mean something like this? https://ghostbin.co/paste/vs2htd

Comment: I tested it in some fake payload and it is almost OK - there are problems with wrong names of variables in some places - and problem is that thread doesn't display error message when there is something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code with small modifications - mostly problem was with wrong names of variable (because then are very similar)

To make sure I use names `executor1`, `executor2` and `executor2` has to be create before `while True` because it has to exist all time when threads are used.

If you have `def filtering(filtered_link)` then you have to use the same name `filtered_link` in `submit(..., filtered_link=...)`

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

found_products = []

site_catalog = [
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sneakers",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/T-shirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sweatshirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Shirts"
]


def threading_feeds():
    print('[threading_feeds] running')
    # Create own thread for each URL as we want to run concurrent
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor1:
        executor1.map(monitor_feed, site_catalog)


def monitor_feed(link: str) -> None:
    print('[monitor_feed] start')
    
    old_payload = ['old'] # product_data(...)

    # executor has to exist all time
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor2:

        while True:
            print('[monitor_feed] run loop')

            new_payload = ['new1', 'new2', 'new3']  # product_data(...)
            
            if old_payload != new_payload:
                for product_link in new_payload:
                    if product_link not in found_products:
                        print(f'Detected new link -> {product_link} | From -> {link}')
                        
                        executor2.submit(filtering, filtered_link=product_link)
                        #executor2.submit(filtering, product_link)
                        
                        print("Continue")
                        
            time.sleep(2)
    
def filtering(filtered_link):
    # More code will be added in the future to handle logical code parts
    #...
    # Test
    print(f'[filtering]: start: {filtered_link}')
    time.sleep(60)
    print(f'[filtering]: end: {filtered_link}')


# --- start --

threading_feeds()
```

Comment: Siema and awesome! I was close! Haha, Regarding no error displayed is probably due to you need to catch the try except in both ThreadPools to be able to caught the errors. Thank you so much for all the help. Dziekuje 

Comment: now you have to test it on real data to see if all is OK. Good Luck (PL: Powodzenia)

Comment: Yupp will do, Im half polish aswell but terrible  at writting  I will come back if I get any problem else I will mark it as the answer!